# MBProgressHUD with synchronous server response issue, code included

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I'm having issues getting the MBProgressHUD to work properly. With the code below, it simply shows and hides instantly AFTER the server request is made. I understand this is due to the fact that the request and loading indicator code are run during the same loop of the main thread and therefore the showing of the loading indicator does not execute until after the current main thread loop iteration.

Here is the code. What can I do to make the MBProgressHUD show WHILE the server request is being made? This application is made with ARC.

```
if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view) { [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view animated:YES]; }

    NSString *urlString = (get) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?action=%@&forumId=%@&%@", kForumDirectorUrl, action, kForumIdentifier, get] :
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?action=%@&forumId=%@", kForumDirectorUrl, action, kForumIdentifier];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
    id returnObject = (json) ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] options:0 error:nil] :
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view) { [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view animated:YES]; }

    return returnObject;
```

Comment: Make the request on a background thread and stop the progress indicator when it's complete.

Comment: ... or use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...]` and hide the HUD in the completion block.

Comment: Asynchronous will not work in this scenario as the resulting response is required by the application to continue.

Comment: @BraydonBatungbacal You are anyways blocking the user interactions by showing hud until request is downloaded. It will be okay to use async method for download.

Comment: No updates to the user interface are done while you block the main thread with the synchronous call `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]`. You will have to change your code to use asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a synchronous request here is what happens:

1. Show MBProgressHUD
2. Perform the request
3. Hide MBProgressHUD

All of them are performed in the same cycle: when you perform some graphics operations in your code, they are all performed at the end of the cycle - until your code ends. You can think about it like a "queue" (it isn't a real queue, but it can help you to understanding how iOS core works).

So you are pushing these graphics operations in this virtual queue, and then they are performed togheter, that's why you see the ProgressHUD for a moment.

You have to change your request from synchronous to **asynchronous** to avoid the problem, so you will break these 3 operation into 2 groups:

1. Show MBProgressHUD
2. Perform the request

And then when operations ends:

1. Hide MBProgressHUD

So your MBProgressHUD will be shown until the request ends.

Comment: My understanding of the asynchronous approach is that it would not work because my application requires the response as a table data source for parsing?

Comment: With asynchronous wouldn't the code continue to execute for the table data iterations while the url request is run on a background thread? Which is what I don't want

Comment: Yes, it will continue to work but, if well done, it won't crash: the first time you will have 0 result, so your table will be empty; when you'll receive the response you can refresh table and you will see your data.

Answer (score 0):

make an async call of MBHUD in this way

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                  [self showProgress:@"Login Started"];
              });
```

Comment: This won't help as long as the main thread is blocked with `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]`.

Comment: He just need to send whole this method in separated block thread. Like this:  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(beginSyncingAll) toTarget:self withObject:nil];  And use  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ for MBHud showing